# Thread communication using SendMessage

Tags: multithreading, communication, sendmessage

my question is : how can I use SendMessage() to implement thread communication between two threads, one with a window (GUI) and the other with no window?

The problem is that SendMessage() needs a handle (HWND)?

Another detail about my project : Two threads, one running managed code (the one with the user interface), and the other running native code (the one without window)

Thank you very much!

Comment: SendMessage is an incredibly dangerous function to be using in a multi-threaded environment because it isn't thread-safe and can result in deadlocks (I speak from experience).

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest creating a hidden window.  When using postthreadmessage, there is a chance that your message could get lost (ie: if a messagebox is running the message loop).

More info about that at:

http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2005/04/26/412116.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you should try to use [PostMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644946(VS.85).aspx) or [PostThreadMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644946(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: I like PostThreadMessage a lot.
Is there a blockant version of this function? Because PostThreadMessage returns without waiting for the callee to process the message.

Comment: No. It wouldn't be too hard to implement a blocking version - use PostThreadMessage, and then have the calling thread block on an event that the callee will set when it has processed the message

Answer (score 2):

If the thread has no window, no message queue, and no message dispatcher, then it's going to be hard to a message to it.  It is common for threads to create hidden windows just for communication purposes (take a look with Windows Spy and you'll see plenty of examples).

One alternative is to use shared memory and a synchronization primitive such an event or semaphore.  Another alternative is to use pipes.

Answer (score 2):

what @jdigital said. Note that if you create a hidden window, and your thread does not already implement a message loop (either in regular win32-speak, or one in the context of a COM STA -- and if you have no idea what I'm talking about then one probably does not exist in your thread), you'll also want to create a message loop as well. ATL makes it fairly easy with `_AtlModule.RunMessageLoop();` Unfortunately this also means the thread in question is probably going to need to be event-driven while it is in the message loop. You can do tricky things like MsgWaitForMultipleObjects, but it gets hairy.

Here's an example of [hidden windows](http://www.wehlou.com/Code/atl_hidden_windows.htm) if you're familiar with ATL/COM. I went through this pain a while back and thought there was a useful discussion on microsoft.public.vc.atl, but the best I can find now is [this post](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.vc.atl/browse_thread/thread/3d43957b8f0cbe46/63ca5ad8b9b93212?#63ca5ad8b9b93212). which goes into some detail about variants of message loops (what to do differently if you have keystroke accelerators or modeless windows, sounds like you don't in your application).